# jQuery dialog overlay changing position at different div opacities

Tags: jquery, css, html, overlay, jquery-ui-dialog

Can somebody help me to overlay a div in a jQuery dialog? In my case the image (ajax loading) should be centered horizontally and vertically in the div. It also shouldn't be affected by the div-opacity.

Have a look at my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zhw8B/

I'm really not a CSS expert. :-(

Thank you very much for your efforts

Kind regards
shub01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have your overlay not be affected by the opacity of `#div1`, it cannot be placed inside `#div1`. You'll need to use a container:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div id="div1">
        <form/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course it is the container that you'll be opening in a dialog:

```
$("#container").dialog({
  modal: true
});
```

You'll need to split your CSS into two selectors. Since `.overlay` is nothing but a `DIV`, you'll need to assign it a height.

```
#div1 {
    opacity: .5;
}

.overlay {
    background-image: url(http://www.x-works.de/images/ajax_loader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
}
```

Finally, to center the overlay, set it to `left: 50%` (which will make it start after 50% of the container), and adjust it to minus half its size, to get the *center* of the overlay, rather than its *left corner* to be at the center. Then repeat for height:

```
.overlay {
    background-image: url(http://www.x-works.de/images/ajax_loader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -24px;
    margin-top: -24px;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/veH4y/)

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for your help! Can you also help me to center the loading image only within the `#div1`? http://jsfiddle.net/veH4y/1/

Comment: @shub: The container was only meant to contain the `#div1` and `.overlay`. Treat that as one functional unit. If you want to add more stuff, you should wrap all of that. Also, add `#container { position: relative; }`, to make sure that's the offset parent of the `.overlay`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GxWpz/)

Answer (score 1):

one solution could be the use of `:after` peuso-element. Check the following css:

```
.overlay{
    opacity:.5
}
.ui-dialog:after {
    background-image: url("http://www.x-works.de/images/ajax_loader.gif");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity:1;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/U4JGK/

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the loader here instead:

```
.ui-autocomplete-loading {
background: transparent url(http://www.x-works.de/images/ajax_loader.gif) no-repeat !important;
width:48px;
margin:0px auto;
```